# How to get data fulfilling two conditions in excel?

Tags: database, excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements

I am currently working on an excel data sheet exampled as below.My aim is to get the cell value which fulfills the two conditions.

.........A............B...............C................D

======= ======= ======= =======

1.......ID......sales......Response

2...... N01.... 122....... Positive

3...... N02.... 151....... Positive

4...... N03.... 123....... Negative

5...... N04.... 124....... Positive

6...... N05.... 154....... Negative

7...... N06.... 162....... Negative

8...... N07.... 124....... Positive

9...... N08.... 108....... Positive

10.....N09.... 137........ Negative

11.....N10.... 109........ Negative

Now I want the **Maximum Sales Value** whose *Response* is **Positive**.
So here the First condition is *I want Maximum sales value*  and second is *The Response is Positive*.
    I want such record using formulas only.So please help if you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=MAX(IF(C2:C11="Positive",B2:B11))
```

this is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See image for reference:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, That Works.
And suppose I have a _Fourth colomn_ **Percentage**, and I want to find the **Sales** for which _Response_ is **Positive** and _Percentage_ is **Maximum**. Help me for this.

Comment: I have used this array foormula

{=INDEX(B2:B11,MATCH(MAX(IF(C2:AC11="Positive",D2:D11)),D2:D11,0))}

Comment: @PavanV - `C2:AC11="Positive"` should be `C2:C11="Positive"`

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
=INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(MAX(IF(C2:C11="Positive",D2:D11)),D2:D11))
```

(also array formula)
I would have commented on the other answer but don't have enough points yet...